# Regular expressions

Tags: python

Hi does anyone know why this code returns a "No" and the other one returns a "Yes"?

```
import re
b="@gmail.com"
x=re.findall(r"\Bgmail",b)
if x:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")  # <<<



import re
b="agmail.com"
x=re.findall(r"\Bgmail",b)
if x:
    print("Yes") # <<<
else:
    print("No")
```

Comment: What other results did you expect? What did you intend the `\B` to do if not this?

Comment: \B is **not \b**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `\b` is word boundary, `\B` is the opposite

---

Your regex `"\Bgmail"` ask for :

- `gmail` word
- with **NO** word boundary before it

```
@gmail.com
^^ there is a word boundary between these 2 chars, so regex don't match

agmail.com
^^ there is NO word boundary between these 2 chars, so regex match
```

---

#### [`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/VCYsN5/1)

#### [`Word boundaries doc`](https://launchschool.com/books/regex/read/anchors#word-bounds)